# Find all continuous functions $f$ over reals satisfying $f(x)^2+x^2=1$

Tags: calculus

> Find all continuous functions $f$ over reals satisfying $f(x)^2+x^2=1$.

I thought to solve we can just do $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Doesn't that solve it? I think it doesn't since they  aren't defined over the reals.

Comment: There can be no such function. If $|x|>1$, no real valued $f$ can satisfy the equation.

Comment: Defined 'over reals'?

Comment: @copper.hat I think it would suffice to say either square root function is not defined over the reals so it is impossible.

Comment: The $f(x)$ you wrote down isn't a function.